# Select by expression functions in QGIS 2.8.2 (Windows)?

Tags: qgis, expression

Please forgive me if this is obvious, but having opened a newly installed version of QGIS on Windows, I can't seem to see the list of functions normally present (as shown in the Mac image) in the 'Select by expression' box. Anyone know how to get these back?

[image: Select by expression (Windows)]

[image: Select by expression (Mac)]

Comment: The Functions works with the 2.8.2 64bit (on Windows 7) http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html what os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the divider to the right. That should unhide the function list.

[image]

Comment: Yes, one has to be aware of those self snapping group widgets. The same applies to 'Drag and drop designer' and 'Edit UI' of the Layer Properties > Fields tab.

Answer (score 0):

!@#$%^& and ! Are you saying that it is impossible to program these things so they never get self-adjusted into oblivion? After hours of frustration I happened to stumble on this one here. This merits strongly suggesting that there should be a FAQ on the front page of the manual to give unsuspecting users some hints for when obvious things don't seem to work anymore after upgrades. Was ready to advise my students to go save money to buy arcgis!